# How to color particular dates in JQuery UI Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I've tried many codes but no one works .. 
I juste want to highlight or change the background color from a particular date.

```
(function() {

function Datepicker() {
}

var klass = Datepicker.prototype;
var self = Datepicker;
SCF.Datepicker = Datepicker;

self.init = function() {
self.bindEvents();
};

self.bindEvents = function() {
$(self.element).datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    minDate: -20000,
    maxDate: "+240M", //+1M +10D
    dayNamesMin: ['Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam', 'Dim'],
    firstDay: 1
});
};

// vars
self.element = ".datepicker-placeholder";

}());
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: look at this : http://www.spiceforms.com/blog/highlight-particular-dates-jquery-ui-datepicker/